# How to display data type of all columns in a sql query

Tags: sql, types, sqldatatypes

I have tried this query, but it returns an error :

```
Select DATA_TYPE 
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customers' AND
COLUMN_NAME IN (Select *
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where TABLE_NAME = 'Customers');
```

Error :

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
Select COLUMN_NAME , DATA_TYPE 
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customers'
```

BTW if you use the `in` clause, then select only a single column in the subquery and not all

```
where COLUMN_NAME IN (Select col from table)
```

and not

```
where COLUMN_NAME IN (Select * from table)
```

Comment: How would I display Column Name next to column data type?

Comment: Add it to the list after `select`. I updated the answer. That is very basic SQL. Please take a tutorial to get used to the basic stuff

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful with collation and use:

```
Select DATA_TYPE 
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE lower(TABLE_NAME) = 'customers';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATA_TYPE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Customers'
```

Or a better solution would be

```
SELECT  c.name AS [Column Name],
       t.Name AS [Data type]
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN  sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Customers')
```